# ACCESS/SQL: inner join syntax

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hello
I'm having problems making an inner join in access.

Could somebody correct my syntax ? I don't understand where the error comes from.

Tables:
AC (msn, reg)
failure (id, msn)

what I'm trying to do:
I want to list the number of failures by AC, displaying the ac.msn & .reg, and the number of failures for each of these.

Here is what I came up with:

```
SELECT  failure.msn, ac.reg, Count(failure.failid) AS failures
FROM Failure, AC
INNER JOIN AC
USING msn
GROUP BY failure.msn
ORDER BY Count(failure.failid)
```

but this returns "syntax error in FROM clause"

I don't understand why. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are doing the INNER JOIN, you don't need to also include the table in the FROM clause...

```
SELECT
    Failure.msn, 
    AC.reg, 
    COUNT(Failure.failid) AS failures
FROM
    Failure
INNER JOIN
    AC
ON
    AC.msn = Failure.msn
GROUP BY
    Failure.msn,
    AC.reg
ORDER BY
    3
```

Comment: works perfectly, thanks :) What does ORDER BY 3 means ? refers to the 3rd listing in the SELECT ?

Comment: This just means order by the third column. Glad to help.